# TexLive: Why compiling in linux is much faster than windows?

Tags: texlive, compiling, windows, linux

I use TexLive in both linux and windows. However, the project compiles very fast (below 1 sec.) in linux while it takes between 10 to 20 seconds on windows (in the same machine).

This has happened to me on every machine. In fact, Texlive on windows sometimes is fast (compiles in 1 sec or worse) and sometimes is slow (on the same file)!

Why is Texlive so slow on windows?

Comment: I can approve this: independently of Windows version (xp or 7), my notebook with openSuse always has been much faster at compiling *.tex files. Editor on both: Emacs. Wonderful question, by the way.

Comment: The windows file system has always been inferior compared to the one in linux. You can install latex on an SSD or RAM disk, perhaps the difference will become neglible here...

Comment: I have the feeling that maybe the computation time is short itself! In fact, the windows binaries of TexLive have multiple halts, and each halt lasts for 5-10 seconds. I am sure it is independent of the win version because I've tested it on many machines. I don't know **why do these halts occure" and how can we get rid of it?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Maybe, but I am wondering how much data does Texlive need? If it is a disk access or disk seek-time issue, why does it occure in Windows and not in linux? Doesn't windows have a cache mechanism that provide fast access to files on further reads? Besides, 20-30 seconds is a very large time, compared to the seek time of a HDD. If it is a seek-time issue, it means that TexLive wants to open ~1000 files in each compile, which seems very unlikely.

Comment: you can write `\message{TIME: \pdfelapsedtime^^J}` as first line in your file and right after `\begin{document}`. This might track down a huge lot of file accesses (and yes: tex loads tons of files on each compile). Then compare the numbers on windows and linux and you might get a feeling if it is the preamble which takes so long or if it is the document typesetting.

Comment: @Ali I would check first that the TEXINPUTS is set up correctly on the windows side. If there are missing `!!` then TeX will search the filesystem for input files such as `article.cls` and without using the kpsewhich class then that can easily be ~1000 directory opens given the size of a texlive tree these days.

Comment: Several comments. Most people run MikTeX on Windows, not TeXLive. There are differences in the file structure, and MiKTeX is always prompt to install new packages as needed. That means that there is at least an extra service running in the background ready to connect to CTAN. But the major difference could come from the compiler call inside your LaTeX editor. You might be calling `pdflatex` in linux and `latex -> dvi2ps -> pstopdf` in Windows

Comment: Out of curiosity I asked a Windows-guru colleague, and he said if TeX is opening a lot of files, it could be the horrible [his words] Windows directory and file management calls. He also said to try Windows 10, which apparently does things differently.

Comment: I do not find this surprising.  Windows is not open source on purpose.  One of those purposes is so that non-microsoft software does not work as well running on Windows.

Comment: @AFeldman Do you have any evidence for that or is it just a conspiracy theory? Because, if true, that is almost certainly illegal in several jurisdictions and would surely fall foul of many competition laws. Note that your claim is much stronger than the claim that non-MS software runs worse than MS software on Windows. I have no idea if that's true, but even if it is, it would not establish that this is by deliberate design.

Comment: @cfr  Just conspiracy theory. :) But then again Microsoft has a remarkable track record of intentional anti-competitive behavior.

Comment: Another possibility is that Windows antivirus software (even the built-in Windows Defender) is checking files as they are opened. The more files, the longer the wait, and it would depend in priority of service. One way to find out: Open Windows Task Manager, then compile your TeX code (keeping the Task Manager visible), and see what uses up the CPU and disk access.

Comment: I remember to have had this thought in mind when I switched from Ubuntu to Windows (do not criticize me, it wasn't much of a choice), compilation seemed to take far longer. But then again everything was slower than usual... Upgrading to w10 helped but a lot of bugs came along (non within TeX). Anyways, I solved all issues with a brand new SSD, now everything is in order! `:D`

Comment: @Clément without some more data the question can not be answered. E.g the engine isn't mentioned.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, fair enough, I just assumed that this behavior was independent from the engine, or that the engine was `pdfTeX`, I don't know.

Comment: @Clément: well it could be independant from the engine if as David suggested some is wrong with the file name database. But it could be also with xetex related to the font cache or with lualatex to the font database.  Or something else. In general I would say that a difference of nearly 20 seconds must be due to some configuration problem.

Comment: Another data point: "to try Windows 10, which apparently does things differently" --> unfortunately, no. A middle sized document of 20-25 pages with text, images, bib, hyperref, acronyms, simple booktab tables, fancyhdr and some others can take between 5 and 10 minutes (not seconds) to compile on Win10. If I need to compile with a high frequency (for troubleshooting) I usually sync to my Linux laptop and compile there, which takes a few seconds on the same document. I look like a real computer savvy guy (which I'm not) working on two machines at the same time :D

Comment: Any update on this after 4 years?

Comment: I use `pdflatex` on Cygwin because I'm locked into my command-line ways.  Because I have a very secured machine and I'm not admin, I was locked into a 2015 Cygwin installation.  There, `pdflatex` ran relatively quickly.  In the past 1.5 years, I found that the upgraded Cygwin was negatively impacted in 2 ways: (i) X-windows no longer mapped pixel-to-pixel to my laptop screen, causing...problems; (ii) `pdflatex` ran several times longer. I thought they might be related, but even when I used `mintty` instead of `xterm`, `pdflatex` still ran slow. Even though the new system is Windows 10 + SSD.

Comment: I've also noticed this issue! Texlive and Miktex both work much faster on Linux.
In fact, the tex installation on my WSL Linux is much faster than the exact same tex installation on my native Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which OS TeXLive was originally developed for, but the fact that it is cross-platform may mean that it's using a sub-optimal (from a performance standpoint) compatibility layer that may be affecting performance.

I have observed a similar phenomenon using TeXLive on Cygwin, which isn't an apples-to-apples comparison, but it is a data point nonetheless.

Another thing to try would be using MiKTeX, which is designed specifically for Windows. It has pretty fast compile time for me.

Comment: MikTeX is much slower for me using Windows 10.

Comment: @Al_Fh For me MikTeX and TexLive have indistinguishable performance on Windows, both for small and large documents. Both come nowhere near the "press compile, done instantly" speed I am seeing on my work PC (Open Suse Leap, 15.1). Though I am comparing an 2-year old gaming laptop with disabled turboboost (for a more quiet fan) with a new rather powerful desktop here. Both SSD-only.